# Split values over multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows)

I have the following output from a stored procedure and was wondering the best way to split the values into multiple rows.

```
reference   name                            subjects       subjectstitle
LL9X81MT    Making and Decorating Pottery   F06,F27,F38       NULL
```

I need to trim the subjects field at the comma's and duplicate the information over three rows so the data would be as follows.

```
reference   name                            subjects       subjectstitle
LL9X81MT    Making and Decorating Pottery   F06       NULL
LL9X81MT    Making and Decorating Pottery   F27       NULL
LL9X81MT    Making and Decorating Pottery   F38       NULL
```

I'm using MS SQL Server 2008 to setup these SP's and just need some help on how to split the subjects field up.

Thanks,

Comment: How does the data get into that format? Can you not return it properly in the first place?

Comment: Simply use this:
select refrence, sbj  from TableX
LATERAL VIEW explode(split(subjects, '[,]')) subjectTable AS sbj;

Answer (score 15):

You will want to use some sort of table-valued split function similar to this:

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[Split](@String varchar(MAX), @Delimiter char(1))       
returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(MAX))       
as       
begin      
    declare @idx int       
    declare @slice varchar(8000)       

    select @idx = 1       
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       

    while @idx!= 0       
    begin       
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
        if @idx!=0       
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
        else       
            set @slice = @String       

        if(len(@slice)>0)  
            insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)       

        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
        if len(@String) = 0 break       
    end   
return 
end;
```

You can then use `outer apply` to join with yourtable:

```
select t1.reference,
  t1.name,
  t1.subjectstitle,
  i.items subjects
from yourtable t1
outer apply dbo.split(t1.subjects, ',') i
```

Giving a result like this:

```
| REFERENCE |                          NAME | SUBJECTSTITLE | SUBJECTS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  LL9X81MT | Making and Decorating Pottery |        (null) |      F06 |
|  LL9X81MT | Making and Decorating Pottery |        (null) |      F27 |
|  LL9X81MT | Making and Decorating Pottery |        (null) |      F38 |
```

See [SQL fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/db383/4)

If you want to do this without a split function, then you can use CTE:

```
;with cte (reference, name, subjectstitle, subjectitem, subjects) as
(
  select reference,
    name,
    subjectstitle,
    cast(left(subjects, charindex(',',subjects+',')-1) as varchar(50)) subjectitem,
         stuff(subjects, 1, charindex(',',subjects+','), '') subjects
  from yourtable
  union all
  select reference,
    name,
    subjectstitle,
    cast(left(subjects, charindex(',',subjects+',')-1) as varchar(50)) ,
    stuff(subjects, 1, charindex(',',subjects+','), '') subjects
  from cte
  where subjects > ''
) 
select reference, name, subjectstitle, subjectitem
from cte
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/db383/7)

Comment: +1 : You *may* be better placed with `OUTER APPLY` though, just in case...

Comment: @Dems you are probably right, updated thanks for the correction.

Comment: On this borad there is allready a topic on this and looks like was solved there

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows

Comment: @Jester - You should flag the question as a duplicate. This is what you should do

Comment: So many duplicate questions getting answered on SO these days

Comment: @Mahmound - Ty for the hind didn't do that yet.

Answer (score 10):

This will do without a split function

```
SELECT T1.reference, T1.name, T2.my_Splits AS subjects, T1.subtitile
FROM
 (
  SELECT *,
  CAST('<X>'+replace(T.subjects,',','</X><X>')+'</X>' as XML) as my_Xml 
  FROM [yourTable] T
 ) T1
 CROSS APPLY
 ( 
 SELECT my_Data.D.value('.','varchar(50)') as my_Splits
 FROM T1.my_Xml.nodes('X') as my_Data(D)
 ) T2
```

Comment: Very nice.  Works great.

Comment: This is great.  Is there a way to also add a sequence number to go along with the split values?

Comment: I think figured it out.  Add an additional column right above "my_splits" in T2: ```row_number() over (order by my_data.D) as sequence_num,```

Comment: much more performant.  I went from 1700 reads to 28.  Makes an ugly execution plan but I don't care!