# Splitting strings into multiple rows in R

Tags: string, r, reshape

This has been asked in various places for SQL, but can't find a simple way to do it in R

I have a dataset like this

```
                                                             Ids    v1  v2  v3  v4  v5
548|14721,678|17604,716|18316,732|18505,745|18626,752|18716 9186    639 9045    316 28396
548|14721,678|17603,716|18316,732|18507,745|18626,752|18716 9041    598 8897    283 28054
548|14722,678|17603,716|18316,732|18507,745|18626,752|18716 8799    588 8669    246 27433
548|14721,678|17603,716|18316,732|18505,745|18626,752|18715 8914    614 8765    273 27347
716|18316,745|18626                                         4113    497 4050    270 27267
548|14722,678|17604,716|18316,732|18507,745|18626,752|18716 8829    589 8713    254 25270
```

I want to split based on the first column on comma and create a row for each entry, repeating the entries in the rest of the rows.

The function I have written is

```
split.data <- function(data, split = ",") {
  y <- NULL
  for( i in 1:nrow(data)){
    y <- rbind(y,cbind(data.frame(unlist(strsplit(as.character(data[i,1]), split = split))),data[i,-1]))
  }
  names(y) <- names(data)
  y <- sapply(y,as.character)
  return(as.data.frame(y))
}
```

This works but its extremely slow. Is there a way to vectorize this and make it faster. The file I have has over 5000 such rows and it takes a while to run.

Related articles I have found for SQL:
[Split values over multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159526/split-values-over-multiple-rows)
[Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Updated answer (21 Oct 2013)

These steps can be combined if you use `concat.split.multiple` from my "splitstackshape" package. This function makes use of `count.fields` automatically, so it shouldn't suffer from the problem mentioned in the comments:

```
library(splitstackshape)
out <- concat.split.multiple(mydf, "Ids", seps=",", "long")
head(out)
#     v1  v2   v3  v4    v5 time       Ids
# 1 9186 639 9045 316 28396    1 548|14721
# 2 9041 598 8897 283 28054    1 548|14721
# 3 8799 588 8669 246 27433    1 548|14722
# 4 8914 614 8765 273 27347    1 548|14721
# 5 4113 497 4050 270 27267    1 716|18316
# 6 8829 589 8713 254 25270    1 548|14722
tail(out)
#      v1  v2   v3  v4    v5 time       Ids
# 31 9186 639 9045 316 28396    6 752|18716
# 32 9041 598 8897 283 28054    6 752|18716
# 33 8799 588 8669 246 27433    6 752|18716
# 34 8914 614 8765 273 27347    6 752|18715
# 35 4113 497 4050 270 27267    6      <NA>
# 36 8829 589 8713 254 25270    6 752|18716
```

---

#### Original Answer (27 Feb 2013)

You need to do a combination of splitting the "Ids" strings followed by "reshaping" your data (if I understand your goal correctly).

Instead of splitting the way you did, I've gone ahead and taken advantage of `read.csv` and the argument `fill = TRUE`. Note that if the values in your "Ids" column are currently factors, you'll need to use `text = as.character(mydf$Ids)` instead.

Here's how I'd proceed:

```
mydf2 <- cbind(read.csv(text = mydf$Ids, fill = TRUE, header = FALSE), mydf[-1])
mydf2
#          V1        V2        V3        V4        V5        V6   v1  v2   v3  v4    v5
# 1 548|14721 678|17604 716|18316 732|18505 745|18626 752|18716 9186 639 9045 316 28396
# 2 548|14721 678|17603 716|18316 732|18507 745|18626 752|18716 9041 598 8897 283 28054
# 3 548|14722 678|17603 716|18316 732|18507 745|18626 752|18716 8799 588 8669 246 27433
# 4 548|14721 678|17603 716|18316 732|18505 745|18626 752|18715 8914 614 8765 273 27347
# 5 716|18316 745|18626                                         4113 497 4050 270 27267
# 6 548|14722 678|17604 716|18316 732|18507 745|18626 752|18716 8829 589 8713 254 25270
```

That data is currently in a "wide" format. Let's make it into a "long" format. The `reshape` function needs a little bit of information on how to proceed. In particular, it needs to know:

- Which columns are indicative of "id" variables. Counter-intuitively to the names from *your* dataset, these are *not* the values from your original "Ids" variable, but the other variables that were present. ("v1" - "v5" (lower-case "v") at positions 7 through 11 in the "mydf2" dataset). Obviously, for your actual data, you need to specify the actual columns that are to be treated as `idvar`s.
- Which columns "vary" and need to be "stacked" in the "long" format. In this case, it's the new variables that were created when we used `read.csv`, and by manually checking their indexes, we can see that they are in positions 1 through 6. Obviously, you would need to specify the column numbers from your actual dataset.

For the example dataset you provided, we would use `reshape` as follows:

```
mydf3 <- reshape(mydf2, direction = "long", idvar=7:ncol(mydf2), 
                 varying=1:6, sep = "")
rownames(mydf3) <- NULL
```

Here's the `head` and `tail` of the resulting `data.frame`:

```
> head(mydf3)
    v1  v2   v3  v4    v5 time         V
1 9186 639 9045 316 28396    1 548|14721
2 9041 598 8897 283 28054    1 548|14721
3 8799 588 8669 246 27433    1 548|14722
4 8914 614 8765 273 27347    1 548|14721
5 4113 497 4050 270 27267    1 716|18316
6 8829 589 8713 254 25270    1 548|14722
> tail(mydf3)
     v1  v2   v3  v4    v5 time         V
31 9186 639 9045 316 28396    6 752|18716
32 9041 598 8897 283 28054    6 752|18716
33 8799 588 8669 246 27433    6 752|18716
34 8914 614 8765 273 27347    6 752|18715
35 4113 497 4050 270 27267    6          
36 8829 589 8713 254 25270    6 752|18716
```

---

This is all assuming we are starting with an object named "mydf" that looks like this:

```
mydf <- structure(list(Ids = c("548|14721,678|17604,716|18316,732|18505,745|18626,752|18716", 
  "548|14721,678|17603,716|18316,732|18507,745|18626,752|18716", 
  "548|14722,678|17603,716|18316,732|18507,745|18626,752|18716", 
  "548|14721,678|17603,716|18316,732|18505,745|18626,752|18715", 
  "716|18316,745|18626", "548|14722,678|17604,716|18316,732|18507,745|18626,752|18716"
  ), v1 = c(9186L, 9041L, 8799L, 8914L, 4113L, 8829L), v2 = c(639L, 
  598L, 588L, 614L, 497L, 589L), v3 = c(9045L, 8897L, 8669L, 8765L, 
  4050L, 8713L), v4 = c(316L, 283L, 246L, 273L, 270L, 254L), v5 = c(28396L, 
  28054L, 27433L, 27347L, 27267L, 25270L)), .Names = c("Ids", "v1", 
  "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
  -6L))
```

Comment: +1! good use of fill=TRUE to deal with the problem at source.

Comment: Great!. Your solution works. I will need to make some changes as its not certain that there will always be 6 columns after splitting. I have updated the request to the next step. Let me know if that makes any difference.

Comment: I found an issue with using the read.csv approach. It worked on the sample data I provided, but when applied to the full data there were rows with more than 6 ids in the string and instead of adding another column, it adds another row and thus the cbind fails.

Comment: @RohitDas My guess is that `read.csv` assumes that there are 5 fields from the first few lines of input, and then fills in anything that is less than 5. If it's greater than 5, it assumes that there's a new line. If you know what the maximum number of ID's is(from something like `max(sapply(lapply(df$Ids,strsplit,split=','),length))`), then you can add `colClasses=rep.int(NA_character,6)` (or whatever the max number of IDs is) as an argument to `read.csv`.

Comment: @RohitDas, just modify the reshape command to correctly identify the column numbers for the columns which are not varying (lower case v1-v5) as the idvars, and the column numbers for the columns which need to be stacked as the varying argument.

Comment: just an update that the function `concat.split.multiple` is now updated to `cSplit`.