# SQL Server : split CSV

Tags: sql-server, database, csv

I have a function to split CSVs up. I have data like this:

```
identifier  values   
123         abc,def,ghi
124         jre,ds,qwert
```

And I want the output to be:

```
123 abc
123 def
123 ghi
124 jre
124 ds
124 qwert
```

How do I go about doing this?

Thanks,
Harry

This is what I currently have;

```
 SELECT CustomRecordsetId, LTRIM(Value) AS my_values
 FROM
  (
   SELECT *,
   CAST('<X>'+replace(Value,',','</X><X>')+'</X>' as XML) as my_Xml 
   FROM dbo.CustomFieldValue where CustomFieldId=177
  ) T1
  CROSS APPLY
  ( 
  SELECT my_Data.D.value('.','varchar(50)') as my_Splits
  FROM T1.my_Xml.nodes('X') as my_Data(D)
  ) T2
```

Although this is returning;

```
id  |       values
596 |   151, 313
596 |   151, 313
603 |   165
604 |   187
605 |   174
606 |   181, 182
606 |   181, 182
```

Comment: As a side note. Don't store your data this way.

Comment: As a foot note. Show us what you've tried.

Comment: I'm trying the first link as we speak. I'm not very good with mssql commands (well, db in general except for nosql).

Zane: I don't, it's a horrible practice. I'm doing a database export from a horrid piece of software where I have to do a lookup, a lookup, a join and then another lookup, just to get a related field (when they could just be next to each other in adjacent columns).

Unfortunately, I no longer have what I did, since I was just replacing the code. In future, I will keep what I have done though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried a number of solutions, but this is the one that works best IMO.

```
 SELECT identifier, LTRIM(T2.my_Splits) AS my_values
 FROM
  (
   SELECT *,
   CAST('<X>'+replace(T.values,',','</X><X>')+'</X>' as XML) as my_Xml 
   FROM YOURTABLE T
  ) T1
  CROSS APPLY
  ( 
  SELECT my_Data.D.value('.','varchar(50)') as my_Splits
  FROM T1.my_Xml.nodes('X') as my_Data(D)
  ) T2
```

Comment: I have tried this code now, and amended my original post. Any tips? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Never mind, I was meant to use my_Splits and not my_values, I don't know why that didn't occur to me..

Comment: I can't really take credit for this answer.  It comes from this SO question, but I didn't have the time to look it up before.  And the solution is not the accepted answer.  Still KAF is the real author of this genius little snippet. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159526/split-values-over-multiple-rows

Comment: I've hardly used SO except for lurking, is there a way to credit him for it? (or is it just a case of giving him an up vote?).

I didn't even realize that you could use XML..