# MySQL query to get name words across ids

Tags: mysql, select

Have a bit of a strange query request for our MySQL database.

Table "product" is like this:

```
brandid int
shopid int
name varchar(255)
```

name is always 1+ words separated by " ". For example "Lenovo laptop X1".

I need to get the all the words that appears in names for 2+ brandid and 2+ shopid (i.e. to be selected, a word must appear in products for at least 2 different brandid's and at least 2 different shopids's).

Someone got an idea for writing such a query?

PS: Performance is not critical, but it might be worth mentioning that the table has ~3 million rows...

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159526/split-values-over-multiple-rows to see how you can split the names to rows per word. once you have this, the rest should be pretty simple

Comment: MATCH AGAINST https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html